# Which annotation will execute first while using all annotations in TestNG Framework?

Tags: testng

If we use all annotations of TestNG in our program, which annotation will be executed first? Please clear my doubt that actually asked in interview.

Comment: Have u looked at the official docs - https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

Answer (score 1):

Following execution sequence will be followed when a TestNG test executes

```
@BeforeSuite
@BeforeTest
@BeforeClass
@BeforeMethod
@AfterMethod
@AfterClass
@AfterTest
@AfterSuite
```

So to answer your question @BeforeSuite is the first annotation to be executed.